# How to ignore non minified file upload?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp

I'm using `Visual Studio Code` with the plugin [FTP-KR](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ruakr.ftp-kr) and I would like to ask a question on the ignore module, I actually have this configuration:

```
{
    "host": "x.x.x.x",
    "username": "foo",
    "password": "foofoo",
    "remotePath": "/public_html/test",
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "port": 0,
    "fileNameEncoding": "utf8",
    "autoUpload": true,
    "autoDelete": true,
    "autoDownload": false,
    "ignoreRemoteModification": true,
    "ignore": [
        ".git",
        "/.vscode"
    ]
}
```

as you can see I setup as ignore the following directories:

```
.git
./vscode
```

is possible ignore the javascript file which does not end with `.min.js`? So all the files that just and with `.js`?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can put non minified js files in a folder and ignore it , and keep the minified js files outside  .

like this :

```
    {
        "host": "x.x.x.x",
        "username": "foo",
        "password": "foofoo",
        "remotePath": "/public_html/test",
        "protocol": "ftp",
        "port": 0,
        "fileNameEncoding": "utf8",
        "autoUpload": true,
        "autoDelete": true,
        "autoDownload": false,
        "ignoreRemoteModification": true,
        "ignore": [
            ".git",
            "/.vscode",
            "/assets/js/not-minified"
        ]
    }
```